# Am I using CRYPT_BLOWFISH correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, blowfish

I am about to use this for a user password system but I first want to make sure I'm doing it correctly. Here is my test code:

```
function generateBlowfishSalt() {
    $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./';
    $numChars = strlen($chars);
    $salt = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < 22; ++$i) {
        $salt .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $numChars - 1)];
    }

    return $salt;
}

$password = 'foo';
$salt = generateBlowfishSalt();
$hash1 = crypt($password, '$2a$12$' . $salt);
$hash2 = crypt($password, $hash1);
$compare = ($hash1 == $hash2);

printf('password: %s</br>', $password);
printf('salt: %s</br>', $salt);
printf('hash1: %s</br>', $hash1);
printf('hash2: %s</br>', $hash2);
printf('compare: ' . $compare);
```

Here is a sample output:

```
password: foo
salt: MYVJ32OqLcMGBar3pUa.0S
hash1: $2a$12$MYVJ32OqLcMGBar3pUa.0OTRwv6UX0bcxnSmheKOcqjvqvCrM/p2q
hash2: $2a$12$MYVJ32OqLcMGBar3pUa.0OTRwv6UX0bcxnSmheKOcqjvqvCrM/p2q
compare: 1
```

My main questions are:

1. Am I generating the 22 character salt correctly? Some implementations I've seen use `base64_encode()` to generate the salt. Do I need to do that?
2. Is it correct to store the whole `$hash1` value in the database and not store a separate salt value since `$hash1` will have the salt in it and that's all I need to verify the password?
3. On the PHP `crypt()` document page the `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` example has a trailing `$` for the salt argument(it's this: `'$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$'`). But in all the examples I've seen no one uses the trailing `$`. Is it optional?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the salt correctly. Just has to be random. There are many different methods for random generation of this. Some people use it in addition to date times, etc. Also, longer salts do not mean much as it will be cut off anyways. It requires a certain length, at least in terms of crypt(). So if a little extra padding makes you feel better, go for it.

Your suppose to store the salt in the database. I had trouble understanding that at first. The whole point of a salt is only to make it take longer to rainbow table the passwords with a huge list of possible passwords. Correction, in addition, it also helps with 2 or more passwords that are the same, which is bound to happen. If so, the hashes are still going to be different due to the random salts.

As for crypt() keep testing it until it looks and is the same length as the one on the php DOC for PHP, but yes it looks correct.

Comment: Isn't the salt random? I use mt_rand() to generate it. I don't think I need to store a separate salt value on top of the value returned by crypt() because the value returned by crypt() has almost the whole salt in it. Moreover, I only need the value returned by the first call to crypt() in order to verify the password.

Comment: Yes, you do not need to do anything extra. You are generating random salt.I am pretty sure I said "You are doing the salt correctly". Just reiterating it. You have the right ideas.